# Video is a black box on video with 'muted' and 'playsinline' on iOS Safari (no 'autoplay')

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have a nextjs project where I want to load the inline videos on my page but start paused. So I have the following code:

```
<video muted playsInline loop>
    <source src={item.video.mediaItemUrl} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I have my own `onClick`/`onTap` code to play and pause the video when the user wants to.

This works fine on chrome on android, desktop and iOS but in Safari the video loads as a black rectangle. The only way I've managed to make it load on Safari is by adding the `autoplay` attribute but that's the problem, I don't want the video to autoplay, only when the user taps on it (it's a carousel of videos).

I've tried a couple of hacky attempts such as having the `autoplay` attribute set but then calling `pause()` in a `setTimeout` after a few ms but as you can expect it doesn't work the same way every time and it's a bit of a mess.

If anyone else has tackled this, I would love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem is now solved but below is some ideas to experiment with...

**Possible solutions:**

**1.** Does adding `preload="auto"` help to fix the issue?

```
<video preload="auto" muted playsInline loop>
```

**2.** About using `setTimeout` more correctly..

Don't set `autoplay` (keep it auto-paused). The **Timer** handler function should

- First pause the video with `video.pause();` (if lucky, it might even show a picture)
- Secondly now seek the video time to zero with `video.currentTime = 0;`

You first set `pause` to avoid the seek part also causing an auto play in some browsers.

**PS:** It's also possible the problem is with the video encoding itself. For example if the MP4 does not have its metadata at the front of file. Investigate that possibilty if still not getting a picture whilst paused at page startup.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I'll have a go and see where I get!